# Swift 4.2 EventKit get all Events to the selected calendar on TableView didSelectedRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, eventkit

I'm loading all my calendars in a tableview where every calendar is represented in a cell.
Now I want to print all the events of the calendar of the cell when I tap the cell. 
The Problem is, with the code you see I get the events of **all** calendars.

How can I tell the function only to look in the calendar I tapped in tableview?

```swift
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let calendarTitle = calendars![indexPath.row].title
    print(calendarTitle)
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    print("Current \(calendar)")

    var oneDayAgoComponents = DateComponents()
    oneDayAgoComponents.day = -1
    let oneDayAgo = calendar.date(byAdding: oneDayAgoComponents, to: Date())

    var oneDayFromNowComponents = DateComponents()
    oneDayFromNowComponents.day = 7
    let oneDayFromNow = calendar.date(byAdding: oneDayFromNowComponents, to: Date())

    var predicate: NSPredicate? = nil
    if let anAgo = oneDayAgo, let aNow = oneDayFromNow {
        predicate = eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: anAgo, end: aNow, calendars: nil)

    }

    var events: [EKEvent]? = nil
    if let aPredicate = predicate {
        events = eventStore.events(matching: aPredicate)

        for event in events! {
            print(event.title)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `predicate = eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: anAgo, end: aNow, calendars: nil)` doesn't take into account the calendar you have selected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to pass the calendar in the `calendars` parameter of `predicateForEvents`

```
let rowCalendar = calendars![indexPath.row]
let calendarTitle = rowCalendar.title
print(calendarTitle)

...

if let anAgo = oneDayAgo, let aNow = oneDayFromNow {
    predicate = eventStore.predicateForEvents(withStart: anAgo, end: aNow, calendars: [rowCalendar])
}
```

And please declare the data source array as **non-optional** empty array as you are force unwrapping it anyway

```
var calendars = [EKCalendar]()
```